# How can I get a memblock structure from Linux kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Due to academic reasons I need to get and read a memblock structure and its memblock_type from Linux kernel. I’ve successfully written a kernel module using C that copies the data from kernel to user, but have no idea how to get a memblock structure. I don’t really see any getter in linux/memblock.h. Is there any way to read this structure?